# How can I solve the situation below?

Tags: r, installation, failed-installation

I'm trying to install R 4.2.3 for Mac OS (Intel processor), but I always receive an error message warning that the installation failed. Does anyone know how to solve that?

[image]

I hope someone can help me because I've checked everything I could on my computer and found nothing wrong...

Comment: Not much to know here, but ... uninstall both R and (if it registers as installed despite the error above) RStudio. Then reinstall R first, make sure it is complete, then reattempt RStudio.

Comment: you need to list steps what you did and where you get an install file- just seeing error message is not informative